# Why ExportAsFixedFormat method (Excel) have not params as we see in the save settings dialog?

Tags: excel, vba

In basic Microsoft Office applications (Word, Excel, Visio, PowerPoint) since 2010 we can save document as PDF, and in all applications we can define next two parameters:

1. `Documents structure tags for accessibility` in `Include non-printing information` group;
2. `ISO 19005-1 compliant (PDF/A)` in `PDF options` group.

Including in Excel, but it is in Excel this parameters is absent in arguments of [ExportAsFixedFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat) methods of [Workbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat) or [Worksheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.exportasfixedformat).

If I set various value of this properties in Options dialog box then results PDF files is various.

How can I control these export settings from VBA code?

[Screenshot from Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugH6B.png)

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44489554/1521579

Comment: Thanks, but what about `Documents structure tags for accessibility`?

Comment: Maybe referencing the adobe library would open up some options [this article](http://khkonsulting.com/2009/03/adobe-acrobat-and-vba-an-introduction/) is old, but could lead to something